# Vlan issue with linux kernel 3.x

Tags: ssh, vlan

I have a strange issue with linux hosts running kernel 3.x (e.g fedora 16, ubuntu 11.10), I am unable to SSH and traceroute (only tests done currently) hanging when travelling over a vlan network partition.

I have setup a test network with 2 hosts and a cisco router in the middle, SSH will hang when trying to connect between them.
If i replace the OS on the hosts to say Fedora 12 the connection works correctly.

Has anyone experienced this, have a solution?

Comment: How is this a vlan issue and not just a normal connectivity issue?  Does it work when on a non-vlan?

Comment: yes it does work on a non-vlan, sadly the cisco 861 router i wish to install into our network doesn't use non-vlan routing

Comment: So you confirmed by changing routers?  Did anything else change when you changed routers?  Are the vlans tagged or just configured on the ports?  The reason I ask is that a host has no visibility of the vlan status of a port unless it is tagged.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c02678487&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en) article on the HP website. I was looking up a different problem but I came across your question and the article and I thought it might help.

> ### Solution
>
> Even though this was reported as a bug with vlan lockups on a bonded set running in balance-alb mode, the kernel patch appears to have resolve the issue.
>
> [Click here to access the technical article available at](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/leavinghp?url=https%3A%2F%2Fbugzilla.redhat.com%2Fshow_bug.cgi%3Fid%3D630540&desc=https%3A%2F%2Fbugzilla.redhat.com%2Fshow_bug.cgi%3Fid%3D630540&lc=en&cc=us) https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=630540.
>
> > NOTE:The above-mentioned web link will take to a non-HP Web site. HP does not control and is not responsible for information outside of the HP Web site.
>
> [RHEL5.5] soft lockup on vlan with bonding in balance-alb mode [rhel-5.5.z]    in kernel 2.6.18-194.19.1.el5  linux-2.6-net-bonding-fix-alb-mode-to-balance-traffic-on-vlans.patch    errata-xmlrpc 2010-11-09 13:07:22 EST
>
> An advisory has been issued which should help the problem described in this bug report. This report is therefore being closed with a resolution of ERRATA. For more information on therefore solution and/or where to find the updated files, please follow the link below. You may reopen this bug report if the solution does not work for you.
>
> [Click here to access the technical article available at](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/leavinghp?url=http%3A%2F%2Frhn.redhat.com%2Ferrata%2FRHSA-2010-0839.html&desc=http%3A%2F%2Frhn.redhat.com%2Ferrata%2FRHSA-2010-0839.html&lc=en&cc=us) http://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2010-0839.html.
>
> > NOTE:The above-mentioned web link will take to a non-HP Web site. HP does not control and is not responsible for information outside of the HP Web site.
>
> The user upgraded the kernel and resulting in full communications being restored on all vlan and non-vlan channels.